# Assign random numbers to letters in list

Tags: python

"In each word, replace the letters with a number, keeping in mind that for each word separated by a space the sum of its digits is a number squared. Find the number represented by each letter."

The list is:

```
words = ['MY', 'NAME', 'IS', 'E']
```

This is my code so far:

```
    import random 

words = ['MY', 'NAME', 'IS', 'E']

word_map = {'M': 4, 
            'Y': 2, 
            'N': 6,
            'A': 4,
            'M': 2,
            'E': 4,
            'I': 6,
            'S': 8,
            'E': 2}

word_val = []
for word in words: 
    word.val.append(word_map[word])

print(word_val)
```

However, it doesn't print the letters and its numbers, and I wanted to assign a number to each letter, because after each letter has its number, they have to be added. For example, if 'M' = 2, and 'Y' = 4, they have to be added like 'MY' = 6

For the final output, I wanted to print each set of letters like:
**MY:4, NAME: 8**

Comment: if that is the case the values are not randomly assign, but mapped to your dictionary. You want them to be mapped or really randomly assigned? importing random does nothing if you don't use it

Comment: You aren't going to get the output you are looking for. E is overwritten once in your dict and M is overwritten once.

Comment: {'M': 2, 'Y': 2, 'N': 6, 'A': 4, 'E': 2, 'I': 6, 'S': 8}

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte yes, I want it to be mapped, but when I mapped it in my original code, it wouldn't work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement this would be to use the `.replace()` method for the string along with the `word_map` dictionary. This will create a string version of the number to be generated. You can then convert the string using `int()`.

```
word_val = []
for word in words:
    for w in word:
          word = word.replace(w, word_map[w])    
    word_val.append(int(word))
```

Comment: I changed it, but maybe I'm adding the print() with the wrong values. I'm using print(word_val) however, nothing happens. I want to print each set of words with the corresponding number.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
words = ['MY', 'NAME', 'IS', 'E']

word_map = {'M': 4, 
            'Y': 2, 
            'N': 6,
            'A': 4,
            'M': 2,
            'E': 4,
            'I': 6,
            'S': 8,
            'E': 2}

word_val = []
for word in words: 
    val = 0
    for letter in word:
        val += word_map[letter]
    word_val.append((word, val))

print(word_val)

# Output: [('MY', 6), ('NAME', 8), ('IS', 18), ('E', 4)]
```